# Istio Sidecar - doc description vs. live cluster behavior

Tags: connection, istio, istio-sidecar

my question is related to the [Istio Sidecar](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/sidecar/)

First : In the description of the Sidecar the following is stated:

> When determining the Sidecar configuration to be applied to a workload
> instance, preference will be given to the resource with a
> workloadSelector that selects this workload instance, over a Sidecar
> configuration without any workloadSelector.

Second: In the spec table, in the description of egress, following is written:

> If not specified, inherits the system detected defaults from the
> namespace-wide or the global default Sidecar.

So, I've tried to apply two sidecars on the "default" namespace, for the **bookinfo** example.

1.first sidecar is default (selector-less) in the default namespace with an egress field restricting the connections

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default-sidecar
  namespace: default
spec:
  egress:
    - hosts:
      - "./details.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - "./ratings.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

2. second sidecar, is with a selector selecting the ratings app, but without an egress field:

```
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
    kind: Sidecar
    metadata:
      name: ratings-selected
      namespace: default
    spec:
      workloadSelector:
        labels:
          app: ratings
      ingress:
      - port:
          number: 9080
          protocol: TCP
          name: somename
        defaultEndpoint: unix:///var/run/someuds.sock
```

So, From the egress description above, I expect that the ratings app may connect only with the  details and ratings apps (the egress of the default sidecar)
But on live cluster the behavior I get is that it can connect with all other services in my mesh (including productpage and reviews from bookinfo - default namespace)
which means that the second sidecar overrides the first one - and cancels the "egress"
connections specified in it even if the second sidecar does not include an egress field.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens?